# Possible tag synonym [scroll] and [scrolling]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

[scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scroll) and [scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrolling) appear to be about the same thing. They both don't strike me as being too useful, though, but I wouldn't request deletion yet.

Comment: I always tag my magic scrolls of teleportation with them...

Answer (score 3):

I recomment using the longer and more explicit [scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrolling) as a master, not [scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scroll).

PlasmaHH will just have to [move his magic scrolls](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262373/possible-tag-synonym-scroll-and-scrolling#comment52178_262373) to [rpg.se](http://rpg.stackexchange.com), and finally decide whether they are [<kbd>spells</kbd>](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spells) or [<kbd>magic items</kbd>](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-items).

Other tags to synonym to that:

[scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scrollable) [vertical-scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/vertical-scrolling) [horizontal-scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/horizontal-scrolling) and [scroller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scroller)

The other similar tags concentrate on specific tool-sets or techniques for scrolling and should thus better stay.